# Using [Authorize] in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I have used [Authorize] but when redirect to login view I can login any username or password so what is the problem and also checking user logged or not?

```
public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Panel model, string Username, string Password)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.Username == Username && model.Password == Password)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Test");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong username or password");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()

        {

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following test is wrong and it will always return true:

```
if (model.Username == Username && model.Password == Password)
```

The Panel model's `Username` and `Password` properties are bound from the request and have the same values as the `Username` and `Password` arguments.

You should check the username and password against some database or something. For example if you are using the Membership provider:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Panel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Test");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong username or password");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Complementary information: To check if the user is logged in use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`